# Allowed characters in msbuild project configuration name

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, specifications

Our build scripts must parse /handle project names in msbuild. For making it robust we must consider the allowed set of characters in project configuration names. Besides the common 'Debug' and 'Release' names Visual Studio's Configuration Manager does also accept names like: '1 A ($§ or'. It refuses the characters '|' and '&', though.

Is there a specification of the set of allowed characters? Potentially, there is are upper / lower limits for the lengths of names, too?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2022). It looks like there is no explanation about the naming convention for the project configurations.

I will report this issue and suggest updating the documentation on naming conventions for the project configurations.